# any ways to convert unsigned char to short based on AVX512 cpu intrinics?

Tags: sse, simd, xeon-phi, avx512

I am just reading the cpu intrinic sets of AVX512 in Xeon Phi processors, but it seems that traditional data type converting method in sse doesn't work in avx512, so can I ask that are there any similar cpu set in avx512 can convert unsigned char array to short data type array? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Knight Landing (KNL) unfortunately does not have the `AVX512BW` subset of instructions which includes operations on 8 bit and 16 bit quantities. Otherwise you could just use [_mm512_cvtepu8_epi16](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#avx512techs=AVX512BW&text=_mm512_cvtepu8_epi16&expand=1546,1546).

Eventually the forthcoming Skylake Xeon (Purley - due out 2017 - not to be confused with existing Skylake CPUs) should have AVX-512 which *does* include the `AVX512BW` subset, but until then you're out of luck, although you can of course still use SSE and AVX2 on KNL to do this kind of thing.

Comment: Which parts are you referring to specifically? The "small" Skylake-based Xeons in the E3 family are [available now](http://ark.intel.com/products/codename/37572/Skylake#@Server)

Comment: @njuffa: no, this would be Purley, which will have AVX-512 - I believe it's still due out in 2017 and it will be marketed as Xeon Skylake, even though it's a very different beast than current Skylake branded CPUs.

Comment: Is "Purley" really a very different beast, or simply variants that comprise the E5 and E7 lines of the Skylake generation?

Comment: Well the fact that Purley has AVX-512 makes it very different in my eyes, but it's still technically Skylake. We won't see AVX-512 on consumer CPUs until Cannonlake it seems (2018 ?).

Comment: I got fed up waiting for AVX512 and I moved back to GPGPU and also VR.

Comment: @Zboson: long time no see - I wondered where you'd got to these days!

Comment: @PaulR, well I also moved to a new city and will be starting a new job. I will be working at the company which invented object oriented programming and the first OO programming language (which is ironic since I'm not the biggest fan of OO programming).

Comment: Well I had to Google that but it sounds like a place where the beer is very expensive. ;-) Anyway, good luck in your new job and new city!